# RMOA package error

Tags: r, predict

I started working with RMOA package and I have a problem... The first code for Iris dataset works... The second one for Poker dataset from UCI throw "attempt to apply non-function" error in predict function. I checked if dataset is properly read and it seems to be ok. 
What is wrong here? 
Thak you in advance for any help.

It works:

```
## Hoeffdingtree
hdt <- HoeffdingTree(numericEstimator = "GaussianNumericAttributeClassObserver")

data(iris)
iris <- factorise(iris)
irisdatastream <- datastream_dataframe(data=iris)

trainset <- irisdatastream$get_points(irisdatastream, n = 10, outofpoints = c("stop", "warn", "ignore"))
trainset <- datastream_dataframe(data=trainset)

hdtreetrained <- trainMOA(model = hdt,
                          Species ~ .,
                          data = trainset)

testset <- irisdatastream$get_points(irisdatastream, n = 10, outofpoints = c("stop", "warn", "ignore"))

scores <- predict(hdtreetrained,
                  newdata=testset[, c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width","Petal.Length","Petal.Width")],
                  type="response")
str(scores)
table(scores, testset$Species)
scores <- predict(hdtreetrained, newdata=testset, type="response")
head(scores)
```

It doesn't work:

```
## Hoeffdingtree
hdt <- HoeffdingTree(numericEstimator = "GaussianNumericAttributeClassObserver")

iris <- read.csv("Poker.csv", sep= ",")
iris <- factorise(iris)
irisdatastream <- datastream_dataframe(data=iris)

trainset <- irisdatastream$get_points(irisdatastream, n = 10, outofpoints = c("stop", "warn", "ignore"))
trainset <- datastream_dataframe(data=trainset)

hdtreetrained <- trainMOA(model = hdt,
                          Class ~ .,
                          data = trainset)

testset <- irisdatastream$get_points(irisdatastream, n = 10, outofpoints = c("stop", "warn", "ignore"))

scores <- predict(hdtreetrained,
                  newdata=testset[, c("S1","C1","S2","C2","S3","C3","S4","C4","S5","C5")],
                  type="response")
str(scores)
table(scores, testset$Class)
scores <- predict(hdtreetrained, newdata=testset, type="response")
head(scores)
```

Comment: Where can we access the data? If the codes are exactly the same, probably try loading the script in a fresh R session, or renaming from 'iris' into something different

Comment: This is my .csv file with data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0wtpg2lstad43zo/Poker.csv?dl=0

Comment: I tried both- still doesn't work.

Comment: Where is the dictionary for poker? It seems that `factorise` will not work as expected in `poker` as it only works for character strings

Comment: Anyway, poker dataset has only numerical values so shouldn't it works even without `factorise`?

Comment: If you are classifying the classes and there are no classes to classify, then no, I don't think it would work. On another note, this line presumably won't work either: `table(scores, testset$Species)`. You'll have to switch to `Class`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to switch your factorizing.
Note that, from the help from `factorise`, it will:

> Convert character strings to factors in a dataset.

In reality, this line is an overkill even for the dataset `iris`. Note that when you load iris and check the structure (`str(iris)`). `Species` is already a Factor. The same cannot be said for the dataset `poker`. So another method has to be taken into account. As per the comments, `factorise` will not work:

```
poker$Class <- as.factor(poker$Class)
```

Is what you are looking for.

If you are unwilling to change the name of the dataset for whatever reason, it should be as follows then:

```
iris$Class <- as.factor(iris$Class) #insert this where your current factorise call is
```

As for `factorise` not working as intended. Consider this example:

```
poker <- read.csv("Poker.csv", sep= ",")
all.equal(poker,factorise(poker))
#[1] TRUE
#VS
poker2 <- poker
poker2$Class <- as.factor(poker2$Class)
all.equal(poker,poker2)
#[1] "Component “Class”: Attributes: < target is NULL, current is list >"
#[2] "Component “Class”: target is numeric, current is factor"
```

Compare with this full script (I switched most/all names from irisX to pokerX, so bear that in mind):

```
hdt <- HoeffdingTree(numericEstimator = "GaussianNumericAttributeClassObserver")

poker <- read.csv("Poker.csv", sep= ",")
poker$Class <- as.factor(poker$Class)
pokerdatastream <- datastream_dataframe(data=poker)

trainset <- pokerdatastream$get_points(pokerdatastream, n = 10, outofpoints = c("stop", "warn", "ignore"))
trainset <- datastream_dataframe(data=trainset)

hdtreetrained <- trainMOA(model = hdt,
                          Class ~ .,
                          data = trainset)

testset <- pokerdatastream$get_points(pokerdatastream, n = 10, outofpoints = c("stop", "warn", "ignore"))

scores <- predict(hdtreetrained,
                  newdata=testset[, colnames(testset[1:11])],
                  type="response")
str(scores)
#chr [1:10] "8" "8" "8" "8" "8" "8" "8" "8" "8" "8"
#also switched this line as per the comments, even though it's edited in the OP now
table(scores, testset$Class)
#      
#scores 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
#     8 6 3 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
scores <- predict(hdtreetrained, newdata=testset, type="response")
head(scores)
#[1] "8" "8" "8" "8" "8" "8"
```